# Getting NullPointerException: Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while executing a Azure function app in java

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have simple hello world Azure function app. I am getting the below exception while executing the function app:

```
     Executed 'Functions.functiontest' (Failed, Id=1040b836-9136-4f90-b3fb-c130f8e89172)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.functiontest. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: NullPointerException: 
Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:54)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:53)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer$$Lambda$12/1869197502.run(Unknown Source)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         at service.FunctionApp.carrierMaster(FunctionApp.java:38)
[12/12/2019 4:20:35 PM]         ... 17 more
```

It is a basic functionnapp which returns HelloWorld. I have added some code to implement distributed tracing using Azure. This is the Function app Code:

```
  package service;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.google.protobuf.Message;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.http.HttpEntity;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.logger.InternalLogger;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.Duration;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.RemoteDependencyTelemetry;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.RequestTelemetry;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.RequestTelemetryContext;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.ThreadContext;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.correlation.TelemetryCorrelationUtils;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class FunctionApp {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate rest() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(FunctionApp.class);

    @FunctionName("functiontest")
    public HttpResponseMessage carrierMaster(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET},
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
                                             final ExecutionContext context) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {


            log.debug("Inside the function");

           RequestTelemetryContext context1 = ThreadContext.getRequestTelemetryContext();

            if(context1 == null) {
                InternalLogger.INSTANCE.warn("Context is null");
                log.info("inside context1 try");
               // return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("hello world").build();
            }

            RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = context1.getHttpRequestTelemetry();

           String dependencyId = TelemetryCorrelationUtils.generateChildDependencyId();
            RemoteDependencyTelemetry dependencyTelemetry = new RemoteDependencyTelemetry("Send Data");

            dependencyTelemetry.setId(dependencyId);
            dependencyTelemetry.getContext().getOperation().setId(requestTelemetry.getContext().getOperation().getId());

            dependencyTelemetry.getContext().getOperation().setParentId(requestTelemetry.getId());

            Duration duration = new Duration(0,0,0,0,10); // set the duration 10 millisec as an example.
            dependencyTelemetry.setDuration(duration);

            TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.getActive();
            TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
            telemetryClient.trackDependency(dependencyTelemetry);


            log.debug(request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).toString());


            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("hello world").build();

    }

    @GetMapping("/sample")
    String callApp() {


        return rest().getForObject("http://10.33.92.92:8081/sample/hello", String.class);
    }
}
```

Below is the pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.sams.wms</groupId>
      <artifactId>fnapcicd</artifactId>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>fnapcicd</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
      </parent>
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.apache.camel>2.24.1</org.apache.camel>
        <org.apache.solr>3.5.0</org.apache.solr>
        <org.springboot.starter.web>2.1.5.RELEASE</org.springboot.starter.web>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.3.3</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.3.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>test-java-fa</functionAppName>
        <functionAppRegion>East US</functionAppRegion>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
        <functionResourceGroup>dev-wfm-learning-fns</functionResourceGroup>
        <start-class>com.example.ConverterRoute</start-class>
        <wrapper.version>1.0.22.RELEASE</wrapper.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
        <sonar-jacoco-listeners.version>3.2</sonar-jacoco-listeners.version>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
        </sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
        </sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
      </properties>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>maven.snapshots</id>
          <name>Maven Central Snapshot Repository</name>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven.snapshots</id>
          <name>Maven Central Snapshot Repository</name>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>

      <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <id>proximity</id>
          <name>Walmart Releases</name>
          <url>https://repository.walmart.com/content/repositories/pangaea_releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
          <id>proximity</id>
          <name>Walmart Releases</name>
          <url>https://repository.walmart.com/content/repositories/pangaea_snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
      </distributionManagement>
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-bindy</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-bindy-starter</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-jacksonxml-starter</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-xstream</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
          <artifactId>solr-commons-csv</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.solr}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-azure-starter</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
          <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-example-aggregate -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-example-aggregate</artifactId>
          <version>2.15.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.16.8</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
          <version>${org.apache.camel}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application Insights dependencies-->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-log4j2</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>applicationinsights-web-auto</artifactId>
          <!-- or applicationinsights-web for manual web filter registration -->
          <!-- or applicationinsights-core for bare API -->
          <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
          <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
          <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
              <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <resourceGroup>${functionResourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
              <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
              <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
              <appSettings>
                <!-- Run Azure Function from package file by default -->
                <property>
                  <name>WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE</name>
                  <value>1</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                  <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                  <value>~2</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                  <name>FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME</name>
                  <value>java</value>
                </property>
              </appSettings>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>package-functions</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>package</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                  <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}
                  </outputDirectory>
                  <resources>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/azure
                      </directory>
                      <includes>
                        <include>**</include>
                      </includes>
                    </resource>
                  </resources>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                  <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                  <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                  <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                  <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                  <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <filesets>
                <fileset>
                  <directory>obj</directory>
                </fileset>
              </filesets>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <propertyName>coverageAgent</propertyName>
              <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                  <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                  <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/../target/coverageReport</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                  <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>post-integration-test</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/../target/coverageReport</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
              <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*Test*</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/FT/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*IT*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
              <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
              <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*IT*</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>

    </project>
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Could you please share the whole code including the "import" line in your code and the pom.xml file ?

Comment: Hi @HuryShen, I have added the whole code and the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

please follow below starter and see if it works out..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-function-in-azure

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/azure.html

look at note:

> The Hello function is quite specific:
> It is a java.util.function.Function. It contains the business logic, and it uses a standard Java API to transform one object into another.
> Because it has the @Component annotation, it's a Spring Bean, and by default its name is the same as the class, but starting with a lowercase character: hello. Following this naming convention is important if you want to create other functions in your application. The name must match the Azure Functions name we'll create in the next section.